# Update Labels in a UserControl in TabPage

Tags: c#, winforms

Thanks to stackoverflow I was able to dynamically create tab pages for my project. The issue I'm running into is how to update content in the UserControl I have in my TabPanel TabPages.

Here is how I'm currently creating the Tabs (there is one default tab that isn't created as that will never change all other tabs are created upon frm_load)

```
private void TechnicianInfo()
        {
            var techSheet = smartSheet.SheetResources.GetSheet(
                0000000000000000, // all 0's for security purposes
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);

            // API identifies columns by ID, but it's more convenient to refer to column names
            Dictionary<string, long> technicianMap = new Dictionary<string, long>();

            // Build the column map for easier reference
            foreach (Column column in techSheet.Columns)
                technicianMap.Add(column.Title, (long)column.Id);

            // Let's loop through the rows and add in information
            foreach (Row row in techSheet.Rows)
            {
                Cell techName = row.Cells.First(cell => cell.ColumnId == technicianMap["Technician Name"]);
                Cell techCertified = row.Cells.First(cell => cell.ColumnId == technicianMap["Certified Radios"]);
                Cell techLevel = row.Cells.First(cell => cell.ColumnId == technicianMap["Technician Level"]);
                Cell techEmail = row.Cells.First(cell => cell.ColumnId == technicianMap["Email"]);

                // Dyanmiclly Create Tab Pages with correct info on them
                UserControl newTechnicianControl = new TechnicianControl
                {
                    TechnicianLevel = techLevel.DisplayValue,
                    CertifiedRadios = techCertified.DisplayValue,
                    EmailAddress = techEmail.DisplayValue

                };
                TabPage techPage = new TabPage();
                techPage.Controls.Add(newTechnicianControl);
                techPage.Text = techName.DisplayValue.ToString();
                techPage.Name = "tech_" + techName.DisplayValue.ToLower();
                tcRepairs.TabPages.Add(techPage);
            }
        }
```

During the creation, I'm able to access the properties of the UserControl upon defining it. I have a timer to pull updated information from smartsheets once every hour (please note I'm not pulling all the information I need right now. I want to figure out my issue first before I pull all information). Upon the timers tick event I'd like to call an update function that will update the labels of the UserControls in each TabPage.

I have the UserControl set up with three properties as of right now.

```
public string TechnicianLevel
        {
            get
            {
                return this.lblTechLevel.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                this.lblTechLevel.Text = value;
            }
        }

        public string CertifiedRadios
        {
            get
            {
                return this.lblCertifiedRadios.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                this.lblCertifiedRadios.Text = value;
            }
        }

        public string EmailAddress
        {
            get
            {
                return this.lblEmail.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                this.lblEmail.Text = value;
            }
        }
```

The only way I can think to get this to work is to remove all except the first TabPage and then re-add them. I feel like this method would work but I feel like there should be a better way of being able to update the UserControl in the TabPage.

Comment: Where's the Timer thing? Without it, it's clear what the problem is -- Anyway, when you generate the UserControls (`UserControl newTechnicianControl = new TechnicianControl() { }`), add these Controls to a `List<TechnicianControl>` that you store as a Field. When the Timer ticks, loop the list ad set the Properties of your UserControls. If you have to remove a UserControl, dispose one that is in the List. When the Forms closes,  dispose of all. -- You could also loop the `TabPages` collection and get the `.Controls.OfType<TechnicianControl>().FirstOrDefault()` of each.

Comment: How is the code currently updating the labels? Where is this code?

Comment: @JohnG Right now there is no update call for this section of the code as I can't figure out how to call the properties of the UserControl outside of the UserControl being created. The update function works fine for labels not in a UserControl. It is accessing the UserControl Labels which is the problem when not creating the UserControl.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for the idea on the List<TechnicianControl> I'll give it a try along with the looping idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JohnG it is stated that the TechnicianControl (the usercontrols in question) are being created during the form load. So they do exist.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your previous comments… _”I can't figure out how to call the properties of the UserControl outside of the UserControl being created. “_ … and … _”It is accessing the UserControl Labels which is the problem when not creating the UserControl.”_ … ? …

Comment: @JohnG no worries. I may not of given the best explanation for my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jimi and their idea of looping through the `TabPages`. Below is now currently working for updating the `UserControl` `TechnicianControl` labels. Thanks a lot!

```
private void UpdateTechnicianInfo()
        {
            // API identifies columns by ID, but it's more convenient to refer to column names
            Dictionary<string, long> columnMap = new Dictionary<string, long>();

            var techSheet = smartSheet.SheetResources.GetSheet(
                2589985581885316,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);

            // API identifies columns by ID, but it's more convenient to refer to column names
            Dictionary<string, long> technicianMap = new Dictionary<string, long>();

            // Build the column map for easier reference
            foreach (Column column in techSheet.Columns)
                technicianMap.Add(column.Title, (long)column.Id);

            // Lets loop through the rows and add in information
            foreach (Row row in techSheet.Rows)
            {
                Cell techName = row.Cells.First(cell => cell.ColumnId == technicianMap["Technician Name"]);
                Cell techCertified = row.Cells.First(cell => cell.ColumnId == technicianMap["Certified Radios"]);
                Cell techLevel = row.Cells.First(cell => cell.ColumnId == technicianMap["Technician Level"]);
                Cell techEmail = row.Cells.First(cell => cell.ColumnId == technicianMap["Email"]);

                foreach (TabPage page in tcRepairs.TabPages)
                {
                    TechnicianControl technicianControl2 = page.Controls.OfType<TechnicianControl>().FirstOrDefault();
                    if (technicianControl2 != null && && page.Name == "tech_" + techName.DisplayValue.ToString())
                    {
                        technicianControl2.TechnicianLevel = techName.DisplayValue.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
```